# Which coordinates does fillRect() use?

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, coordinates

This is my first project with AWT/Swing. I'm trying to design a simple cellular automaton. I had some problems choosing a layout manager, now I'm using GridLayout because is the closest I got to what I want. However, when a try to place a cell in the JPanel, the coordinates do not work as I expected. Maybe I should not be extending from JComponent and using fillRect()? Or maybe GridLayout is not the layout I need? The main problem is that the point (0,0) seems to be "moving". **Is fillRect conflicting with GridLayout?**

Note 1: I've tried GridBagLayout but did not work (because I have no idea how to configure it). I've also tried the add(component, x, y) method but it did not work.

Note 2: I did not post the code regarding the State of the Cell because it was not relevant.

Edit: Ok, I wrote an example in a single public class, I don't think I can be more concise and reproduce the same results.

**Solution:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html

This is my code:

```
public class Example{
    class Cell extends JComponent{
        private int x = 0;    //Cell position ?
        private int y = 0;
        public Cell(int x, int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //draw cell
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(x,y,15,15);        
        }
    }
    Example(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        JPanel box = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20,20)){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                setBackground(Color.black);
                //draw grid
                for(int i = 0; i <= this.getHeight(); i += 15){
                    g.drawLine(0,0+i,getWidth(),0+i);
                }
                for(int i = 0; i <= this.getWidth(); i += 15){
                    g.drawLine(0+i,0,0+i,getHeight());
                }
            }
        };
        /*box.add(new Cell(0,0)); //TEST 1
        box.add(new Cell(0,0));
        box.add(new Cell(0,0));
        box.add(new Cell(0,0));*/
        box.add(new Cell(0,0));   //TEST 2
        box.add(new Cell(15,0));
        box.add(new Cell(30,0));
        box.add(new Cell(45,0));
        frame.add(box);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Example();
    }
}
```

And this are the results corresponding to TEST 1 and TEST 2:

[TEST 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EDPH.png)

[TEST 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNTXZ.png)

Comment: *"I did not post the code regarding the State of the Cell because it was not relevant."* Good call. Also don't have 3 public classes. Post one [mcve] as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: If you're doing custom painting, you should read the document [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) which covers a lot of important information. Your question in the post title is possibly answered in [this section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callback), but you should read the entire page. I also agree with Andrew's comment, that if you want specific help with your code you need to post an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All painting is done relative to the component that contains the custom painting, not the panel you add the component to.

So in your case just do the painting from (0, 0).

The layout manager will position the Cell at the location determined by the layout manager.

Note:

A painting method is for painting only. It should NEVER create a component, as your current Box class is doing.

The basic logic is to:

1. create your panel with the desired layout.
2. add components to the panel.
3. the size/location of the components added to the panel will be determined by the layout manager. So in your Cell class you need to implement the `getPreferredSize()` method so the layout manager can use this information to position each component that is added to the panel.

If you want to manage the painting at different locations on the panel, then don't use real components. Instead you keep an ArrayList of shapes that you want to paint. Each shape will contain the location it should be painted. Then you iterate through the ArrayList in the paintComponent() method to paint each shape. For an example of this approach check out the `Draw On Component` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).